# dnsmasq not working oh Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, homebrew, dns

I have a service running on localhost on MacOS High Sierra.

```
curl foo.test
```

does not work, but

```
curl localhost
```

does.

To get to my setup, I installed dns using homebrew,

```
brew install dnsmasq
```

added my configuration to /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf,

```
address=/test/127.0.0.1
```

and added a resolver file /etc/resolver/test:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I've spent a day trying

- `dig foo.test`
- `scutil --dns`
- `dscacheutil -q host -a name foo.test`

and nothing worked.

My eventual issue was not covered anywhere else, so I'm answering it here for someone else.

Comment: same problem on Mojave/10.14.6

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr make sure you start dnsmasq as root.

To diagnose this problem, I used Console.app, and searched for dnsmasq.

1. My first problem revealed in the logs:

   ```
   failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use
   FAILED to start up
   ```

To fix this, make sure dnsmasq is stopped:

```
brew services stop dnsmasq
```

then use Activity Monitor.app to kill any old dnsmasq processes.

After the socket conflict was removed, I attempted to start dnsmasq again:

```
brew services start dnsmasq # does not work
```

and now the logs in Console.app show

```
failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Permission denied
FAILED to start up
```

To fix this, I restarted the service as root:

```
brew services stop dnsmasq
sudo brew services start dnsmasq
```

Now

```
curl foo.test
```

works!

After this journey, I revisited all those dnsmasq help articles I read. The sudo was there all along and I skimmed over it.  I'm posting this for the next person that forgets to start dnsmasq as root.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the job of the .plist launchd configuration in ~/Library/LaunchAgents to declare as which user this server should run?

Comment: Sounds like a security risk, but the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942698/launchagent-run-bash-script-as-root) talks about a solution that uses /Library/LaunchDaemons instead.

Comment: it only works if you use elevated privileges, so why would using the feature that launchd provide for doing that be security risk?

Comment: It _sounds_ like a security risk because you're granting root permissions to a configuration.  As to whether it actually _is_ a security risk, I leave that as an exercise for the reader.